# Bing Map API - Update / Delete Entity

Tags: bing-maps, bing-api

I am trying to use Bing Map API to Update / Delete Entities in an existing Data source, though it is possible, it appears like I have to upload the whole dataset every time after making necessary updates to the relevant entities. Is there an alternative way to update or delete individual entities through API other than using the [Bing Maps Dev Center](https://www.bingmapsportal.com/)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes.

1. Log into the Bing Maps dev center.
2. Select "Data Sources" -> "Managed data sources" at the top of the page.
3. Locate your data source in the list and click edit.
4. Go through your data and make edits or delete items as you see fit. Press "Update" button after making a change to an item.
5. After all your edits are done, press the "Publish" button.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! But I was looking for a way to do this through an API call instead of using the Bing Maps dev Center.

Comment: Ah, in that case, the only option is to download, edit, and reupload the whole data source.

Comment: yeah!, I too thought that is the only option, but just came across the documentation details mentioned above. Downloading and Uploading the whole data set for just one small change to an entity could be too heavy on us, so we will use the "incremental" upload, Thank you so much for your inputs!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a parameter "loadOperation" when invoking the Load Datasource URL

> http://spatial.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Dataflows/LoadDataSource?dataSourceName=dataSourceName&loadOperation=loadOperation&dataLocation=dataLocation&setPublic=setPublic&input=input&output=output&key=masterKey&queryKey=queryKey

If we provide the value "complete" to this parameter it overwrites the entities in the existing data source, however when we provide the value "incremental" it just updates/deletes required entities.

For deleting the entities, we must add a property named __deleteEntity to the schema and set it to 1 or true for each entity that we want to remove.

These details are available in the [documentation link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bingmaps/spatial-data-services/data-source-management-api/load-data-source-dataflow/create-a-load-data-source-job-and-input-entity-data)